# How to renew database in ibm datastage

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I alter my tables in the database. But in IBM DataStage, the tables are not automatically altered, it stays the same like without any alters. How do i renew/reload the database/ the tables in IBM DataStage for the new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no automatic mechanisms.  When you import a table definition, whether using DataStage or InfoSphere Metadata Asset Manager, what you are storing in the common metadata repository is the state of the table as at the time it was imported.
All you can do is to re-import the table definition.
If you altered the table to drop columns, that fact (and not the table definition) may cause your DataStage jobs to fail; you should perform a "where used" analysis against the table definition before importing it anew.

Comment: if i re-import the table definition will it cause any error to my jobs? (my jobs are inputing xlsx file to the table) should i remap / rename the stage columns again?